# How to split a list with named characters

Tags: r

I have a list as below.
I would like to split the elements of the list into a dataframe so that I capture the first, second and last "" in the list. I have spent hours googling but not sure where to start. I tried the `split` function as roman<-split(roman,f=roman$V1) but I got an error and anyway I don't know how to select out the first two and last elements of the vector.

I think things are complicated by the structure of the list. For example one of the columns is

```
> head(dput(roman[,1:6]))
list(structure(c("Gagner", "M", "M", "Department of Surgery, Herbert Wertheim School of Medicine, Florida International University, Miami, FL, USA. gagner.michel@gmail.com.", 
"Department of Surgery, Hôpital du Sacre Coeur, Montreal, Canada. gagner.michel@gmail.com."
), .Names = c("LastName", "ForeName", "Initials", "AffiliationInfo", 
"AffiliationInfo")), structure(c("Braghetto", "I", "I", "Department of Surgery, University Hospital \"Dr. Jose J. Aguirre\". Faculty of Medicine, University of Chile, Santiago, Chile."
), .Names = c("LastName", "ForeName", "Initials", "AffiliationInfo"
)), structure(c("Iwaya", "Yugo", "Y", "Department of Gastroenterology, Nagano Municipal Hospital, Nagano, Japan.", 
"Department of Medicine, Division of Gastroenterology, Shinshu University School of Medicine, Matsumoto, Japan."
), .Names = c("LastName", "ForeName", "Initials", "AffiliationInfo", 
"AffiliationInfo")))
[[1]]
                                                                                                                                LastName 
                                                                                                                                "Gagner" 
                                                                                                                                ForeName 
                                                                                                                                     "M" 
                                                                                                                                Initials 
                                                                                                                                     "M" 
                                                                                                                         AffiliationInfo 
"Department of Surgery, Herbert Wertheim School of Medicine, Florida International University, Miami, FL, USA. gagner.michel@gmail.com." 
                                                                                                                         AffiliationInfo 
                                             "Department of Surgery, Hôpital du Sacre Coeur, Montreal, Canada. gagner.michel@gmail.com." 

[[2]]
                                                                                                                        LastName 
                                                                                                                     "Braghetto" 
                                                                                                                        ForeName 
                                                                                                                             "I" 
                                                                                                                        Initials 
                                                                                                                             "I" 
                                                                                                                 AffiliationInfo 
"Department of Surgery, University Hospital \"Dr. Jose J. Aguirre\". Faculty of Medicine, University of Chile, Santiago, Chile." 

[[3]]
                                                                                                        LastName                                                                                                    "Iwaya"                                                                                                         ForeName                                                                                                     "Yugo" 
                                                                                                        Initials 
                                                                                                             "Y" 
                                                                                                 AffiliationInfo 
                                     "Department of Gastroenterology, Nagano Municipal Hospital, Nagano, Japan." 
                                                                                                 AffiliationInfo 
"Department of Medicine, Division of Gastroenterology, Shinshu University School of Medicine, Matsumoto, Japan."
```

The expected output should be

```
LastName     FirstName     Affiliation
Gagner            M         Department of Surgery, Hôpital du Sacre Coeur, Montreal, Canada. gagner.michel@gmail.com.
Braghetto         I         Department of Surgery, University Hospital \"Dr. Jose J. Aguirre\". Faculty of Medicine, University of Chile, Santiago, Chile
Iwaya            Yugo        Department of Medicine, Division of Gastroenterology, Shinshu University School of Medicine, Matsumoto, Japan
```

Comment: Please provide a `dput` of your data (or `head(dput(mydata))`) and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach using sapply may work for you:

```
t(sapply(data, function(z) z[c(1, length(z) - 1, length(z))]))
```

Comment: Erase this comment

Comment: I was being dumb in the previous comment. I get the error Error in View : arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 2

Comment: lapply returns a list, when applied to your dataset you might need to use do.call(rbind, ...) which you can then use in View